# What is the data integrity of Amazon RDS? Do I need to make automated backups to S3?

Tags: amazon-rds

I host my most valuable data on Amazon RDS. What is the failure rate of Amazon RDS, and what provisions do they have in place for high availability and data redundancy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RDS has plenty of default options for reliability and redundancy - see the [AWS documentation.](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/#features)

Comment: Hi Gareth, thanks for your reply, but this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: The automated backups are binary logs, which may be stored in the same place as the database itself- it doesn't say. Furthermore, there is no indication of what the failure rate is of RDS, which is important in determining what measures are necessary.